# How to pass WebDavURL instead of TCM URI while creating a Component using Core Service?

Tags: tridion

I am able to create Components using Folder TCMURI as shown below:

```
var schemaInfo = client.ReadSchemaFields(
    "tcm:184-1882-8", true, new ReadOptions());

ComponentData component = (ComponentData)client.GetDefaultData(
    ItemType.Component, "tcm:19-454-2");
```

Can I can pass WebDavURL instead of this TCMURI where I want to create Component?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should simply use the WebDAV URL instead of the TCM URI:

```
string folderWebDAVURL = "/webdav/MyPublication/Path/To/Folder";

ComponentData component = (ComponentData)client.GetDefaultData(
    ItemType.Component, folderWebDAVURL);
```

Comment: @Aquarius24 please mark as 'answer' if it's what you needed. Thanks!